# Find corner pattern in data set

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

I have a set of data like these:
[image]

[image]

And I want to recognize this 2 kind of corner shape, is there any way? I wrote s snippet but it sucks.
In this way I am trying to find desc corner (from top to down) and to find asc corner I am "rotating" the dataset and I apply the same algorithm for desc corners.

```
...    
n_rows = len(matrix)
edge_closing_left_total = 0
j=0
for i in range(n_rows):
    edge_closing_left = True
    current_value = matrix[i][j]
    if current_value >= 230:
        current_row = i
        start = j+1
        end = j+1+3
        for k in range(start, end):
            if current_row+2 < n_rows:
                if matrix[current_row][k]<230 and matrix[current_row+1][k]<230 or matrix[current_row+1][k]<230 and matrix[current_row+2][k]<=230:
                    current_row+=1
                else:
                    edge_closing_left = False
                    break
        if edge_closing_left:
            edge_closing_left_total+=1
return edge_closing_left_total
```

[Here](https://file.io/coyqt6hvLDdY) the csv dataset file.

Answer (score 1):

So you need to do template/pattern matching. This could be achieved with correlation. The following code should demonstrate how to do it using scipy:

```py
import pandas as pd
from scipy.signal import correlate2d

img = pd.read_csv('matrix.csv', header=None).to_numpy()
norm = img - img.mean()  # subtract mean to normalize
edge = norm[26:36, :]  # the edge template, adjust if needed

corr = correlate2d(norm, edge, mode='valid')
auto_corr = correlate2d(edge, edge, mode='valid')
corr /= auto_corr  # normalize correlation so that 1 means perfect correlation

corr_cutoff = .9  # 1 is pixel-perfect match
print(f'Found edge template {(corr > corr_cutoff).sum()} times in image when taking a similarity cut-off of {corr_cutoff}')
# Found edge template 2 times in image when taking a similarity cut-off of 0.9
```

The original image (transposed to make it wider than high):

[image]

The edge template looks like this:

[image]

The correlation map looks like this (note: this is actually only 1 px wide but blown up for visualization):

[image]

The thresholded correlation map with cut-off `0.9` (giving 2 results as expected, choose threshold as needed):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer it gave me a really good point of start for a noob, btw at the end after I tried CC and edge functions that do not worked at all unfortunately I used openCV for template matching that worked perfectly.